# ESP32 Drive LED directly

Tags: led

I'm wondering if it's possible to drive an 0805 SMD red LED directly off of an ESP32 pin with a 150ohm resistor. I heard they have max 10mA on each pin.

Comment: It should be no problem, These days LEDs can be illuminated acceptably with only 1-2mA.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but it depends upon the supply voltage.

Just divide the supply voltage - 1.2V or whatever the LED voltage drop is, by .010 to calculate what value resistor you would need.

You could start with placing 2-3 of those 150 Ohm resistors in series just to check the brightness, as LEDs generally glow with less than 20 mA, just not as brightly.

Comment: "*At 3 volts, that gives 3 / .01 = 300.*" I think you need to make it clear that the 3 V is the voltage drop across the resistor, not the supply voltage (as there will be a voltage drop across the LED as well).

Answer (score 1):

You should include your actual LED specs. 0805 SMD is a package size/type, which doesn't actually say what the LED is. Your typical LED runs at 20mA, but will still illuminate at lower currents.

However you can get LEDs that will work at as low as 1mA.

You also didn't say what voltage your ESP is running at? The default is 3.3V, but it can be configured to run at 1.8V. If you're running it at 1.8V your LED wont work.

How much current do you want to run through it? The full 10mA?

If we assume you're running at 3.3V and you have a typical 2.1V forward on your LED and you want to limit it to 10mA then:

R = (3.3-2.1)/0.1 = 120 Ohms

At 150 Ohms you would be limiting it to 8mA, which is probably fine. Assuming you have an LED that illuminates sufficiently at that power. This also assumes you have a typical 2.1V forward voltage.